# pandas vectorized string replace by index

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to change the first two characters in a pandas column string.

```
def shift(x):
x=list(x)
x[0] = '1'
x[1] = '9'
print x  #this prints the correct result as list
##str(x)
return ''.join(x)  ## this works
mc_data['timeshift'] = mc_data['realtime'].map(lambda x: shift(x) )
```

output is `NoneType`

I also tried, `str.slice_replace.map(lambda x: '19')`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing the first two characters, you could build new strings:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ['abcd']*4})
>>> df
      A
0  abcd
1  abcd
2  abcd
3  abcd
>>> df["A"] = "19" + df["A"].str[2:]
>>> df
      A
0  19cd
1  19cd
2  19cd
3  19cd
```